# how to grant full Write/Read files access on specifics folder in android Q

Tags: java, android, storage, android-sdcard

***I noticed that my program on Android Q can not create any folder or save and open a file.*** 
I've read Google's documentation but I did not find the answer or at least I did not understand Because there is a very small sample code, and as I figured out, every time you create a file, you need to open a special window
Someone can tell me **how can I get a full access for special folder in sdcard?**
I do not want to open a different window every time and confirm it

Comment: What does "special folder" mean?

Comment: @CommonsWare for example /sdcard/test

Answer (score 3):

Long term, you have no means of forcing the user to give you access to a `test/` directory on external storage.

You have three main options.

You can use `getExternalFilesDir()`, `getExternalCacheDir()`, or `getExternalMediaDir()`. These are methods on `Context`, and they each return a `File` pointing to a directory on external storage for which you have full read-write filesystem access. From the user's standpoint, these will be under `Android/data/.../`, where `...` is your application ID.

Or, you can use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` and the Storage Access Framework. Using `startActivityForResult()` with an `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` `Intent` will give you a `Uri` that points to a document tree, which may be on external storage, removable storage, or in the cloud. You can call `takePersistableUriPermission()` on a `ContentResolver` to get long-term access to that tree, and you can use `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` to work with that tree. However, this is not filesystem access — it is a bit closer to working with a Web server.

Or, you can add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` to your `<application>` element in the manifest. This will give you legacy filesystem behavior on Android Q devices. This is scheduled to be removed for Android R, so this is not a suitable long-term solution.

I blogged about the Android Q storage changes a lot this year; here is [my last(?) post on it](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html).

Comment: tnx but android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" not work in my app i will try getExternalFilesDir